# What concrete data type implements abstract data type structure in Java?

Tags: java, abstract-data-type

Because a queue is an abstract data type data structure, what concrete data type structure implements it? I saw that a queue is an interface so was unsure how a concrete data type could implement the abstract data type structure.

Comment: You can check what classes implement a given interface by checking [the interface's javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html).

Comment: [`ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) is one such.

Comment: Google: [javadoc Queue](https://www.google.com/search?q=javadoc+queue): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html  All Known Implementing Classes:
AbstractQueue, ArrayBlockingQueue, ArrayDeque, ConcurrentLinkedDeque, ConcurrentLinkedQueue, DelayQueue, LinkedBlockingDeque, LinkedBlockingQueue, LinkedList, LinkedTransferQueue, PriorityBlockingQueue, PriorityQueue, SynchronousQueue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the [Javadoc for `Queue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Queue.html). Notice the seventh line from the top:

> All Known Implementing Classes:

There you will find a list of implementations bundled with any implementation of Java.

> AbstractQueue, ArrayBlockingQueue, ArrayDeque, ConcurrentLinkedDeque, ConcurrentLinkedQueue, DelayQueue, LinkedBlockingDeque, LinkedBlockingQueue, LinkedList, LinkedTransferQueue, PriorityBlockingQueue, PriorityQueue, SynchronousQueue

Third-parties offer implementations as well. For example, [*Google Guava*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava) has implementations such as [`EvictingQueue`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/EvictingQueue.html). And [*Apache Commons*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Commons) offers implementations such as [`CircularFifoQueue`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/queue/CircularFifoQueue.html).

And you can make your own implementation if need be.

Comment: Is not priority queue an abstract data type data structure? Would there not have to be a concrete data type to implement priority queue? @Basil Bourque

Comment: Java comes bundled with a [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue), the [`PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) class. This class is in the list I posted in my Answer.